# php Call to a member function on null?

Tags: php, class, url-routing

I’m following this tutorial from laracast(https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners) and I’m at this episode(16 - Make a Router) in the series

have done all sorts of things to understand one part in this tutorial but I could't after I spent many hours.

The tutorial is about make routes system similar to laravel framework

The route class

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: ahmadz
 * Date: 7/2/2017
 * Time: 7:30 PM
 */
class Router
{

    public $route = [
        'GET' => [],
        'POST' => [],
        ];

    public static function load($file)
    {
          $router = new static;

          require $file;

          return $router;
    }

    public function get($name, $path)
    {
        $this->route['GET'][$name] = $path;
    }

    public function uriProcess($uri, $method)
    {

        if(array_key_exists($uri,$this->route[$method])){
            return   $this->route[$method][$uri];
        }

        throw  new Exception('Error in the uri');
    }
}


    routes file
$router->get('learn/try','controller/index.php');
$router->get('learn/try/contact','controller/contact.php');
```

index file

```
require Router::load('routes.php')->uriProcess(Request::uri(), Request::method());
```

the problem occur when I change this to

```
  public static function load($file)
        {

              require $file;

        }
```

I removed these 2 lines

```
  $router = new static;

   return $router;
```

and then instantiate an object in routes file

```
   $router = new Router;

    $router->get('learn/try','controller/index.php');
    $router->get('learn/try/contact','controller/contact.php');
```

When I do this I get these errors

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function uriProcess() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\try\index.php on line 12 ( ! ) Error:
>   Call to a member function uriProcess() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\learn\try\index.php on line 12

Can you explain way I can't instantiate an object in  routes file instead of load function ?

Comment: Isn't the error message obvious?

Comment: All I'm asking why I can't  call the object in  router file instead of the  load function

Comment: You don't have that object in the router file, instead of an object you have NULL. That's why I asked, perhaps some details about that error message would help?

Comment: look all load function does is requiring a file. for ex: "Router::load('routes.php')" lets say it requires routes file and then passing the returned object to that file. My question is why I can't instantiate an object in routes.php file instead of doing this in load function

Comment: I am sorry to inform you, but that tutorial is quite horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've removed the important part of your code.

In your **load()** method you actually **instantiate** the Router class and then return the newly created $router object.

When you remove the following lines:

```
   $router = new static;

   return $router;
```

The method **load()** returns nothing, hence you get the aforementioned error.

You've to understand, you're trying to use the method uriProcess() which is a method of the class Router, but how do you expect this method to work when you don't have any object in your hand?

You will have to use the code you've shown at the beginning:

```
public static function load($file)
{
    $router = new static;

    require $file;

    return $router;
}
```

**Edit:**

After I understood what you meant, you may try the following code:

```
Router::load('routes.php');

$router = new Router;
$router->uriProcess(Request::uri(), Request::method());

$router->get('learn/try', 'controller/index.php');
$router->get('learn/try/contact', 'controller/contact.php');
```

Comment: Thank you, but all load function does is requiring a file. for ex: "Router::load('routes.php')"   lets say routes file   and then passing the returned object to that file.  My question is why I can't instantiate an object  in  routes.php file  instead of doing this in load function.

Comment: But what about this line? do you still keep it as is?
`require Router::load('routes.php')->uriProcess(Request::uri(), Request::method());`

Comment: yes, because as far as I understand that Router::load  function return an  object to the loaded file  correct ?  if I instantiated an object directly into that loaded file "routes.php"   isn't it the same thing ?

Comment: Well, you're trying to make a "method chaining", but you never return a router object - hence it will never work. (You're trying to chain a method on a null as the error shows).

Comment: I've adjusted my solution to make it fit to your requirements. However, I hope you understand what was wrong with you code.

Comment: it worked when I removed the chaining. now I know the reason why he did it like this.  because of method chaining.   Thank you very much ^^.